# vertices tracking: movie clip editor

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video, tracking, vertex-groups

Background:

- I've a *.png sequence previously rendered: a moving computer
- Now I wanna add the video to the monitor, so need to track the image sequence.
- The *.blend file is the same one I rendered before but I don't want
  to render the whole scene one more time.

How to use vertices groups previously created (monitor) as tracking points?

Any other solution to solve this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have the screen you just need to add a texture to it.

Select the face(s) that make the computer screen and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to make a duplicate. separate as a new object (Press <kbd>P</kbd> ->separate selection).

On the new object enter edit mode
UV unwrap it.
Create an emitter material that uses the video as texture an uses UV coordinates for the mapping.

Move the object to a new layer and create new render layer that contains only the layer with the screen object.

On the compositor import the image sequence you pre-rendered and use an alpha over node to superimpose the render layers that contain the screen and the .PNG sequence as background.

**Other option** (not necesarily easier or as precise) would be to track the 4 edges of the screen on the videoclip editor and create a plane track

see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38332/1853  and [Unable to "Create Plane Track"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23978/unable-to-create-plane-track)